# Как можно изменить данные в SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin4

Описание БД
В базе данных должны записываться даты начала и завершения каждого восхождения, имена и адреса участвовавших в нем альпинистов, название и высота горы, страна и район, где эта гора расположена.

**Как можно предоставить возможность изменить данные о вершине, если на нее не было восхождения?**

```
/* Создание таблицы участников*/
CREATE TABLE ALPINIST
(
    KOD_UCHASTNIKA SERIAL  PRIMARY  KEY,
    NAME_F character(20),
    NAME_E character(20),
    ADRES text
);
/* Создание таблицы восхождений*/
CREATE TABLE VOSHOD
(
    KOD_VOSHOD SERIAL  PRIMARY  KEY,
    NAZVANIE_GRUPPU text,
    START_V date,
    END_V date,
    ID_GORU SERIAL
);
/* Создание таблицы ГОР*/
CREATE TABLE GOR
(
    KOD_GORU SERIAL  PRIMARY  KEY,
    NAZVANIE_GRUPPU text,
    H SERIAL,
    RASPOLOZENIE text
);
/* Создание таблицы УЧАСТНИКИ ВОСХОЖДЕНИЙ*/
CREATE TABLE UCH_VOSHOD
(
    KOD_UCH SERIAL  PRIMARY  KEY,
    VOSHOD SERIAL,
    ALPINIST SERIAL
);
```

Comment: Правильно добавить в структуру внешние ключи с соответствующим ON DELETE CASCADE, после чего просто удалить все записи в таблице восхождений, где восхождения выполняются на нужную гору.

Comment: Структура таблиц - ошибочная. Только поля, объявленные как PRIMARY KEY, должны быть SERIAL. Остальные - INTEGER (возможно, NOT NULL). А то в схеме создаётся хренова гора ненужных генераторов - слишком несуразная цена для создание UNSIGNED поля, проще обойтись CHECK constraint (впрочем, внешние ключи делают такое ограничение ненужным).